# jQuery - Getting certain XML not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Let's say I have an `XML` like this: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&track=Just%20for%20Me&artist=Hinoi%20Team

I'm trying to get the `name` of the `track` and it's not working: I do this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&track="+yourTrack+"&artist="+yourArtist,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
          $(".loading").css("display", "none");
            $(xml).find('track').each(function(){
                var id = $(this).find('id').text();
                console.log("Success!");

                var song = $(this).find('track > name').text();
                var name = $(this).find('artist name').text();
                var album = $(this).find('album title').text();

                $("#more").append("\nSong: " + song);
                $("#more").append("\nArtist: " + name);
                $("#more").append("\nAlbum: " + album);

                $("#more").append("\n\nlast.fm ID: " + id);

            });
        }
    });
```

and the result is this:

```
Song: 
Artist: Hinoi Team
Album: Super Euro Party

last.fm ID: 43135480
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector in this line isn't right:

```
var song = $(this).find('track > name').text();
```

`$(this)` is a `<track>` element. You are looking for another `<track>` element inside of it, which isn't what you need. You are looking for the `<name>`, so use this instead:

```
var song = $('> name', this).text();
```

Comment: Oh, I see. But I tried what you suggested earlier today `var song = $('name', this).text();` and I got `JUST FOR MEHinoi Teameurobeatjpopj-popgreat songsjapanese pop`. It's because there are more than just one `<name>` in this XML tree.

Comment: Thanks. Would I do the same thing with `album` > `image="big"`?

Comment: I'd try `$('> album image[size="large"]', this).text()`